# full form when maximized

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, layout

how do I to convert it:

[image]

to occupy the entire area, when maximized,as notepad:

[image]

how I do this? I hope this is clear. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't set an explicit size (using `Width` and `Height`) on the `Window.Content` (the immediate child of the `Window` element), also set the `HorizontalAlignment` and `VerticalAlignment` to `Stretch`.

Also see: [Layout System](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745058.aspx), [Alignment, Margins & Padding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751709.aspx)

Comment: it's simpler than I imagined. Thanks very much!

Comment: @Jack: Yeah, if you don't change anything you should be fine as the properties are already set to stretch by default. You're welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't set any explicit widths or heights, and also set the HorizontalAlignment and VerticalAlignment to stretch, the inner form will then resize to the parent form size. From there you can use the Margin, Padding, and other properties to precisely dock the inner member inside of the form itself, regardless of whether or not the form changes size. This way the inner content will have the information it needs to resize itself accordingly whenever the main form size is changed.